# perl script to read an excel file using cpan modules

Tags: perl, unix, cpan

I am writing a perl script to read data from an excel file. The script is being written in an unix environment and run on the server, whereas the excel file is available on my Desktop in Windows.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';


use Spreadsheet::Read;

my $workbook = ReadData ("C:/Users/tej/Desktop/Work.xlsx");
say $workbook->[1]{A1};
```

The output gives out a warning saying 
`Use of uninitialized value in say at..... line 10`
And there is no other output being printed. I just wrote a sample code to read the A1 cell value from sheet 1. Later, I need to write a logic to read particular values. For right now, need to fix the error to read and print the excel cell values. Appreciate any help. :)

Comment: Can you try to print `$workbook->[0]{error}` ?

Comment: Do you have https://metacpan.org/release/Spreadsheet-ParseXLSX or https://metacpan.org/release/Spreadsheet-XLSX installed?

Comment: you get that if it can't open the file (e.g. permissions, wrong name etc)

Comment: @John Doe
I get the same error when I try to print $workbook->[0]{error}

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche I see that the file name is correct. How do I check with the permissions. ?

Comment: @simbabque I installed the Spreadsheet modules from cpan by entering into the cpan shell from the command line and installing the modules.
How do I check for what you asked. ?

Comment: You can do `perl -MModule::Name\ 999`.

Comment: When I type the above it says Can't locate Module/Name.pm in @INC

Comment: I fixed the issue. It was about file was not being accessed. I used samba to Map unix disk to Windows Network Drive. 
But now, I get a different error which says : 
Parser for XLSX is not installed at..
Can someone help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. It was about file was not being accessed. I used samba to Map unix disk to Windows Network Drive. But now, I get a different error which says : `Parser for XLSX is not installed at..` Can someone help me to resolve it.

Comment: Well you obviously need to follow the error. Install a XLSX parser

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I figured it out.
Thanks for the help.